# How to discard stdout of child process but keep stdout of parent process?

Tags: c, linux, io-redirection

I am writing a C program in Linux and use `fork` to create a child process. When I run my program using `./test 1 > out.txt` both the parent process and the child processes send information to `stdout`.

I would like the file `out.txt` to only contain output from the parent process and discard all output from the child process.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would redirect the parent's stdout to the file, then when you fork, reopen the stdout handle of the child to go to something else (like /dev/null if you just want to ditch it, or you could open the terminal again if you want it to go back to stdout).

The `dup2` system call can do that. `open` a new one, `close` the old one, then `dup2` the new file descriptor to the old number (1 for stdout).

This is the process the shell itself uses to redirect to a file btw.